# Getting Photos Posted by User

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have following permission for my App.

```
[@"public_profile",@"user_friends",@"user_tagged_places",@"user_photos",@"read_stream"];
```

I am interested in two types of posts and photos from my friends.

- Friend's check in at a place (Shown as "Friend Name" was at "Place Name")
- Friend added Photos at a Place (Shown as "Friend Name" added X photos at "Place Name")

I am being able to get Case 1 by using

```
/friendId/photos/uploaded?with=location
```

The above call did not return me the Photos in Case 2. So I did

```
/friendId/feed?with=location&filter=app_2305272732
```

This returns me the posts in Case 2. The JSON I got back, there were two interesting paramers.

```
{
  "id": "XXXXXXX", 
  "picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/xxxxx", 
  "type": "photo", 
  "status_type": "added_photos", 
  "object_id": "XXXXXXXX", 
  "created_time": "2015-03-09T02:23:28+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2015-03-09T03:18:48+0000"
},
```

picture and object_id. Picture gives me a very small thumbnail image, not an array off images added by my friend. If I do a GET on the Object_id I get

```
  {
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Please advise what I am doing wrong and how I can get Case 2.

Comment: you know you will not get read_stream approved, right?

Comment: Did not know that. So any other way to get Case 2 covered ?

Comment: no, friend permissions are gone so there is no way. the friend would have to authorize the app too.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. When I referred friendId I was referring to app scope ID.

Comment: you can´t even get an app scoped id of a friend, if that friend did not authorize your app

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the places that a person has been tagged in(in a status, photo, video etc), you could use:
/friendId/tagged_places
However to read the user's check-in, read_stream permission will be needed, which is going to be removed anytime and there seems to be no way to get it approved as of now.
As replied earlier, it needs the friend to use the app as well.

Comment: read_stream is not going to be removed. where did you read that? you only don´t get it approved in most cases, but that´s all.